# Querydsl: containsKey does not work in EclipseLink

Tags: eclipselink, querydsl

Consider the following property:

```
public class BusinessUnit {
    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "permissionId")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<Permission, BusinessUnitPermissionApplyType> permissions;

    ...
}
```

The query below does not work with EclipseLink:

```
    List<BusinessUnit> foundBUs = new JPAQuery(em)
            .from(qbu)
            .where(qbu.permissions.containsKey(permission))
            .list(qbu);
```

It gives error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select bu
from BusinessUnit bu
where containsKey(bu.permissions,?1)]. 
[37, 68] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

Of course, there is no `containsKey` function in JPQL. Could therefore `containsKey` be properly emulated? For example, by performing a subquery.

What is another way to perform the same query? I tried to join `permissions`, i.e.:

```
.join(qbu.permissions)
```

But this does not help, since this expression doesn't allow to examine key's value. What would be really helpful is:

```
.joinKey(qbu.permissions, qperm)
.where(qperm.eq(permission))
```

Comment: Could you try with 3.6.2? This is a related closed issue https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1198